# Show extra fields after dropdown selection - VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, show-hide, dropdownbox

I've got an asp classic dropdown box and I need an OnClick event in VBScript to show an additonal two textfields when a selection is made from the dropdown.

Can anyone help me?

I need the two textfields to be hidden first and then visible when requested.

Many thanks,

Mw

```
'-------------- Date Period ------------------

response.write "<tr><td align='left'>Date Period:</td><td>"
response.write "<select name=tbdateselect id=tbdateselect style='width:160px;'>"
response.write "<option value=''>-</option>"
response.write "<option value=Last Month>Last Month</option>"
response.write "<option value=Last (rolling) Month>Last (rolling) Month</option>"
response.write "<option value=Last 6 Months>Last 6 Months</option>"
response.write "<option value=Last 12 Months>Last 12 Months</option>"
response.write "<option value=Last (rolling) 12 Months>Last (rolling) 12 Months</option>"
response.write "<option value=Date Range>Date Range</option>"
response.write "</select>"
response.write "</td></tr>"

'-------------- Date From --------------------
response.write "<tr><td align='left'>Date From:</td><td>"
response.write "<input type=text name=tbdatefrom size=23 value=''><font color=gray><i> yyyy-mm-dd</i></font></td>"
response.write "</td></tr>"

'------------------ Date To ------------------

response.write "<tr><td align='left'>Date To:</td><td>"
response.write "<input type=text name=tbdateto size=23 value=''><font color=gray><i> yyyy-mm-dd</i></font></td>"
response.write "</td></tr></table><font size=4 color=white>*hiddenfield*</font>"
response.write "</td>"
```

I need: If option value = Date Range then show Date From and Date To

Comment: Can you provide some source code?

Comment: Codes example is now shown above

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes your request is an issue of client side.

1st: If you want to output something to the browser you should never use the server side language as long as is possible. Too many mistakes can be done, especially with quotation.

2nd: If you want to do that without extra server request, you have to use Javascript for that. In example, Jquery or another javascript framework makes it easier. I made an jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNx6h/) to demonstrate it.

In case you want do that on server side only -stongly not recommended- you have to do following:

You have to wrap the table into a form. The form has to be always submitted and then you have to get the value from the select box via `response.requestForm("tbdateselect")`. Then change the html output with an `If ... Else .. End If`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I'm after, however I now get an error message saying: Object Required: 'this'
Any idea?

Comment: I did test it with serveral browsers (IE9, FF 21, FF 3.6.28, Safari and Chrom) and couldn't found any errors. Which browser did you use? Have you tried it to merge the code snippets from jsfiddle to one file?

Comment: I am using IE9 and yes all the code is in one file. It is not working in Chrome either

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you. If you don't trust me try  http://home.arcor.de/rvoelsch/do/new2.html . There are no errors. It works even in IE7 mode.